# failed installing driver, Black screen on login

Tags: drivers, ati

Ubuntu 13.10 I tried to install the 13.4 CCC driver from AMD and it seems to have failed, I can login but then I get a black screen with a cursor, it does nothing how do I fix the driver from my install disk of 13.04? Id rather not have to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of login,press `ctrl+Alt+F1`,a virtual terminal will open and login it with your `username` and `password`.
Then run the below commands,

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo shutdown -h now
```

`Poweron` your pc,and i am sure you will get back to your os.